# Is there a Python library that can automatically change the color of certain words in an existing PowerPoint slide?

Tags: python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I've tried Googling with no success. Maybe I'm not asking this in the right way?

I have a PowerPoint slide that is already full of text. Using Python, I want to read in the existing PowerPoint slide and change the word "remember" to bright red, every time it is written. Then, I want to save the PowerPoint slide again.

Does anyone know how to do this or is it impossible with Python?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you two solutions to achieve what you have asked. You can twaek this code according to your needs.

### Solution 1

```py
import os
import win32com.client

#Reading the power point slide
powerpoint = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
ppt = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(os.getcwd()+"\sample.pptx")
ppt.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

#Changing the color of the word 'remember' to bright red
for i in range(1, ppt.Slides.Count+1):
 for shape in ppt.Slides(i).Shapes:
     if shape.HasTextFrame:
         if shape.TextFrame.HasText:
             text = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
             words = text.split()
             for word in words:
                 if word == 'remember':
                     shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(start=text.index(word), length=len(word)).Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

#Saving it back as a power-point slide
ppt.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+"\sample_edited.pptx")
ppt.Close()
powerpoint.Quit()
```

### Solution 2

```py
import os
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation("test.pptx")

for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_text_frame:
            continue
        for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                if "remember" in run.text:
                    run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)

prs.save("test_output.pptx")
```

Comment: That second one changes the whole run to red, not just the word "remember".

The approach would have to be to create 2 or 3 runs out of 1 - with the "remember" run set to red.